# On the topology of disjoint union of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, definition

I wonder if two definitions of disjoint union of topological spaces are equivalent:

> If $X,Y$ are topological spaces, then the disjoint union of topological space $X\sqcup Y$ is the set $X\times\{0\}\cup Y\times\{1\}$ with the topology making $X\times\{0\}$ and $Y\times\{1\}$ clopen and the inclusions $i_X:X\to X\sqcup Y$ and $i_Y:Y\to X\sqcup Y$ homoeomorphisms to their images.

> Same setting as above, we give topology on $X\sqcup Y$ by the largest topology making the inclusions $i_X:X\to X\sqcup Y$ and $i_Y:Y\to X\sqcup Y$ continuous.

The latter definition is the usual definition of disjoint union of topological spaces but in Bredon's Topology and Geometry textbook, he defined in a former way.

Could you explain this?

Comment: I replaced tag "algebraic-topology" by "general-topology".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They’re equivalent. Let $\tau_1$ be the topology on $X\sqcup Y$ defined in the first definition, and note that because $X\times\{0\}$ is open in $\tau_1$, a subset of $X\times\{0\}$ is open in the relative topology on $X\times\{0\}$ if and only if it is actually open in $X\sqcup Y$, i.e., if and only if it is in $\tau_1$. Similarly, a subset of $Y\times\{1\}$ is open in the relative topology on $Y\times\{1\}$ if and only if it is actually in $\tau_1$.

It’s clear that $i_X$ and $i_Y$ are continuous with respect to $\tau_1$, so it only remains to show that $\tau_1$ is maximal with respect to this property. Suppose that $\tau$ is a topology on $X\sqcup Y$ making $i_X$ and $i_Y$ continuous, and let $U\in\tau$. Let $V=i_X^{-1}[U]$ and $W=i_Y^{-1}[U]$. Then $V$ is open in $X$, and $i_X$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $X\times\{0\}$ with respect to $\tau_1$, so $i_X[V]\in\tau_1$. And $i_X[V]=U\cap(X\times\{0\})$, so $U\cap(X\times\{0\})\in\tau_1$. Similarly, $i_Y[W]=U\cap(Y\times\{1\})\in\tau_1$, so $U=i_X[V]\cup i_Y[W]\in\tau_1$. Thus, $\tau\subseteq\tau_1$, and $\tau_1$ is indeed the largest topology on $X\sqcup Y$ making $i_X$ and $i_Y$ continuous.

The second definition is more elegant and expresses an important fact about the topology, but the first definition makes it a bit easier to understand exactly what the open sets are.